# Code to toggle a program

Tags: code-golf

**Challenge**

Write a program that toggles another. Your program should accept exactly two command arguments. Specifically, your two tasks are:

1. If the names of any running processes are identical to argument one, close them and exit
2. If the names of zero running processes are named identical to argument one, spawn one with that name, pass it the second command arg, and exit

The life of the spawned process must be completely independent of your own (think Daemon threads in Java, or Background threads in C#). You are responsible for closing programs that you didn't necessarily start in a past life.

**Example**

Here are two separate examples of how your program might be called.

```
python YourToggler.py Notepad.exe C:\MyTextFile.txt
java MyToggler.java cmd "echo hello world"
```

In the first example, if `Notepad.exe` is currently running, you should close all processes named `Notepad.exe`. Otherwise, you should start one with the argument `C:\MyTextFile.txt`.

**Assumptions**

You can sleep better knowing the following:

- The name passed to you will be a valid program
- You are not responsible for name discrepancies

  - If you are asked to find Notepad, you are not responsible for closing Notepad.exe
- You will be run with the privileges you need to carry out your duty

Comment: Can we can assume no whitespace in the program name and arg?

Answer (score 4):

## Bash+common Linux utilities, 12 or 16 bytes

```
pkill "$1"||"$@"
```

If we can assume no whitespace in the program name and arg, then we can drop the quotes for a score of 12:

```
pkill $1||$@
```

Comment: `killall "$1"||"$@"`

Comment: @user23013 Yes - thanks!

Comment: `pkill` would probably work instead of `killall`.

Comment: @user23013 nice!

Answer (score 0):

## Bash (+ pgrep & xargs) - 83 chars

```
p="$(pgrep -x "$1")";if [ $? = 0 ];then echo "$p"|xargs -n 1 kill;else "$1" "$2";fi
```

Comment: Would `pkill "$p"` work here? Saves you 15 characters.

Answer (score 0):

### AutoIt v3 - 102 chars (97 chars)

```
$a=$CmdLine
If ProcessExists($a[1]) Then
ProcessClose($a[1])
Else
ShellExecute($a[1],$a[2])
EndIf
```

Tried my best to golf it down but there is no shorter function for `ProcessExists()`, `ProcessClose()` and `ShellExecute()`.

Good thing is, that it is working on Windows unlike the Bash answers.

FYI: Using `Run()` instead of `ShellExecute()` requires the full path because it does not take into account executables in your PATH.

---

If we assume that the path is given absolutely like

`toggle.exe C:\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe C:\MyTestFile.txt`

Then that code can be golfed down to 97 chars:

```
$a=$CmdLine
If ProcessExists($a[1]) Then
ProcessClose($a[1])
Else
Run($a[1]&" "&$a[2])
EndIf
```

Note: You have to pass a string to the `Run()`-function like you would type into your Command Prompt but it does not work like it. As written before it is like the Command Prompt without Environment variables.